# Scrollable list

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have table with data that I display at table

Here is Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Companies.ToList());
    }
```

Here is View

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td class="point">
            @(rowNo += 1)
        </td>
        <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size:20px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size:20px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vacancies.FirstOrDefault().VacancyName)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: end;">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Companies", new {id = item.CompanyID})'>
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")'/>
            </a>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Companies", new {id = item.CompanyID})'>
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")'/>
            </a>
            </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Vacancies is Related Data Table to Companies

Company may have 1-10 Vacancies.

How I can show all Vacancies via scrollable list here   `<td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size:20px">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vacancies.FirstOrDefault().VacancyName)
            </td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Vacancies is an IEnumerable, or similar collection object (probably is given your use of FirstOrDefault), you could simply iterate them, much the same way you're iterating the Companies list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td class="point">
        @(rowNo += 1)
    </td>
    <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size:20px">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
    </td>
    <td class="title" style="text-align: center; font-size:20px">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll">
            @foreach (var vacancy in item.Vacancies)
            {
                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(v => vacancy.VacancyName)</div>
            }
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: end;">
        <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Companies", new {id = item.CompanyID})'>
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")'/>
        </a>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Companies", new {id = item.CompanyID})'>
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")'/>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

On an unrelated note, you could, and arguably should, stick to double quotes for HTML attributes:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")" />
```